# Updating an AIR application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, updating

I know there is a built-in update framework inside AIR but finding valid code samples for the latest versions proves to be hard. Some code for simple updating (assuming ActionScript 3, AIR 2.7 and Flex 4.5) would be deeply appreciated (nothing fancy, default styles etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I used to get this working: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air_update_framework.html. It's a good overview (even down to doing a custom update window), and is trivial to implement.

Comment: Updating was changed in 2.5 so you'll want to follow divillysausages's link and use this as well: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/873/cpsid_87300.html